# Application of the Jacobian

Tags: elementary-number-theory, sums-of-squares

I have been stuck on this question for a while now to no success.  Help would be appreciated.

Consider $x$ and $y$ such that $(x, p) =(y, p) = 1$.  For what $p$ does their exist $x$ and $y$ such that $x^2 + y^2 \equiv  0 \pmod p$?

(Also, if you could help answer in terms of the Jacobian that would be appreciated, as that is the relevant section in the book)

Comment: The only connection with Jacobian I can think of is [proof of Fermat's two squares theorem using Minkowski's theorem](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22minkowski+theorem%22+%22sum+of+two+squares%22). This proof can be found, for example, in Chapter 7 of the book I. Stewart and D. Tall, Algebraic Number Theory and Fermat's Last Theorem.

Comment: However, Minkowski's theorem (and Jacobian) is only used here at the point where we want to show that there exist $x$ and $y$ such that $x^2+y^2=p$. (I.e., equality, not just congruence.) Existence of solutions to the congruence is used already before this, in a construction of a lattice to which Minkowski's theorem is applied.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone comes across a question similar and wants to know an answer, I eventually figured it out:

$x^2 + y^2 \equiv 0$ mod p = $x^2 \equiv -y^2$ mod p = $(x/y)^2 \equiv -1$ mod p.

Comment: Such $x,y$ exist if and only if $p$ is not 3 modulo 4.